# How to make mysql restart a service

Tags: python, mysql, web, service

I have a web page that communicates to and sets flags in a mysql database housed on an ubuntu server. Then I have a backend service written in python that runs as root and watches the database for flag-changes/operation-requests; when it sees one, it usually runs a command or something similar.

One of the many commands is to start/stop/restart various services like SMB and NFS and everything works perfectly well for those services. However now I need a control to start/stop/restart MY service, the one that is monitoring for database changes. But if MY service is stopped, I can't restart it via this method since it won't be monitoring the database.

So, I want to know how I should approach restarting this MY service. I was thinking the DB could house and run the code when it sees the flag change, but I've never coded like that before, inside a database.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you have a distribution using `systemd` you can always make a configuration for your application as well and then it's stopped/started/restarted just like everything else.